# Lesser of two evils when using globals via extern

Tags: c, design-patterns, global-variables, extern

I'm working with some old code that uses many global variables. I'm fully aware of many of the disadvantages of using global variables, so my question is not about whether I should be using global variables or not.

After reviewing much of the code I've noticed two patterns and I'm trying to decide which one is worse and why.

A similarity between the two patterns is that the global variables are exposed using "extern".

The main difference between the two patterns is:

1. Some globals are extern'ed/exposed in header files, which are in
   turn included in many source files with a #include
2. Other globals are extern'ed/exposed directly in the source file itself

Which of these two would you believe is worse than the other? And Why?

Would you consider them equally bad? And Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Hide what you can. If they do not need to be visible, don't allow people to use them (by providing their declarations).

2) Use a static if extern is not necessary and… hide what you can.

> Which of these two would you believe is worse than the other? And Why?

The first; Because it is unnecessarily visible to other translations. The second can cause linker errors, but it will take insider knowledge to use correctly in another source/translation. The linker issue can then be resolved by making it `static` (again, if its declaration is visible to one translation).

> Would you consider them equally bad? And Why?

No. If you can hide the globals' implementation and restrict their access, you have done your codebase a favor.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think of C header files as falling into one of three categories: public, private, and protected (not to be confused with the C++ keywords or the same names).  Public are for anything that is meant to be accessed by anyone.  Private are for everything that is meant only for internal implementation of a module (if split into multiple files); these are never visible outside of the module.  Protected are for those items that are not generally expected to be accessed by another module but for some reason or another it needs to be (module coupling can occur here).

To me a symbol (such as a global variable) extern'ed in the C source file instead of a header file is a violation of these "rules" and is interpreted as a code smell.

Hope this helps.